# getting data from AF.Request response

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I need the data from the json response from my Post request call using Alamofire but I cannot access that data for some reason

I tried following along with Alamofire github documentation along with this post [get data from AF responseJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831439/get-data-from-af-responsejson). but neither have helped me.

```
AF.request("https://mbd.cookcountysupernetwork.com/ap/swift_math_get.asp", method: .post,  parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
                print("floop")

        }
```

This is what I see when the code runs

```
success({
    Operand =     (
                {
            A = 12;
        },
                {
            B = 25;
        }
    );
    Operation = Multiply;
    Result = 300;
})
```

so I know the json is there, i just need to access the "Result = 300" so I can set a text box to say "300". but I tried many different methods and I cannot access the information I need from response. Also i do not have a response.result.value which is what almost every post I see about this says to use.

Comment: At first that's not a JSON there are many ";" in it, second I suggest you read documentation of your server side to handling JSON, and so your client JS lib to eval the response as JSON as is ready.

Answer (score 12):

You can access the `Result` value as,

```
AF.request("https://mbd.cookcountysupernetwork.com/ap/swift_math_get.asp", method: .post,  parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                if let json = value as? [String: Any] {
                    print(json["Result"] as? Int)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
```